# nats server not distributing tasks to multiple processes in parallel

Tags: python, async-await, nats.io, nats-streaming-server

I am trying to use nats for job queuing. I want it as an alternative to celery+rabbitmq for my use-case.

I have two scripts.

1. Producer Script that populates the queue.

`producer.py`

```
import nats
from nats.js.api import RetentionPolicy

NATS_HOST = '0.0.0.0'
NATS_PORT = '4222'
DOCUMENT_EXT_SUBJECT = "file_process"

nc = await nats.connect(servers=f"nats://{NATS_HOST}:{NATS_PORT}")
js = nc.jetstream()
await js.add_stream(
    name="sample-stream", 
    subjects=[DOCUMENT_EXT_SUBJECT],
    retention=RetentionPolicy.WORK_QUEUE,
    )

for i in range(20):
    ack = await js.publish(
    subject=DOCUMENT_EXT_SUBJECT, 
    payload=json.dumps(
        {
            "some_load" : "lsome_load", 
        }).encode()
    )
```

2. Consumer Script : `consumer.py`

```
import asyncio
import signal
import sys
import logging

import nats
from nats.js.api import RetentionPolicy, ConsumerConfig, AckPolicy

consumer_config = ConsumerConfig(
    ack_wait=900,
    max_deliver=1, 
    max_ack_pending=1,
    ack_policy=AckPolicy.EXPLICIT
) 

# Nats 
NATS_HOST = '0.0.0.0'
NATS_PORT = '4222'
DOCUMENT_EXT_SUBJECT = "file_process"

MAX_RECONNECT_ATTEMPTS = 10 

## A cpu bound task
def time_consuming_task():
    import time; time.sleep(50)
    return

async def task_cb(msg):
    time_consuming_task()
    await msg.ack()
    print("acknowledged document-extraction !")

    
async def run():

    logging.info("Started Document processing Consumer ...")
    
    async def error_cb(e):
        sys.exit()

    async def disconnected_cb():
        logging.info(f"Got disconnected from NATS server .. Retrying .")

    async def reconnected_cb():
        logging.info("Got reconnected...")

    
    nc = await nats.connect(
        servers=f"nats://{NATS_HOST}:{NATS_PORT}",
        error_cb=error_cb,
        reconnected_cb=reconnected_cb,
        disconnected_cb=disconnected_cb,
        max_reconnect_attempts=MAX_RECONNECT_ATTEMPTS,
    )

    # Create JetStream context.
    js = nc.jetstream()
    ## PERSIST ON THIS SUBJECT
    await js.add_stream(
        subjects=[DOCUMENT_EXT_SUBJECT],
        name="sample-stream", 
        ## Extra
        retention=RetentionPolicy.WORK_QUEUE,
        )
 

    await js.subscribe(
        DOCUMENT_EXT_SUBJECT, 
        stream="sample-stream",
        queue = "worker_queue", # also knowas as "deliver group". In core nats, it's called "queue group".
        cb=task_cb,
        manual_ack=True,
        config=consumer_config,
        )
    
    def signal_handler():
        sys.exit()
    for sig in ('SIGINT', 'SIGTERM'):
        asyncio.get_running_loop().add_signal_handler(getattr(signal, sig), signal_handler)

    await nc.flush()
    logging.info("Done ... ?")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(run())
        loop.run_forever()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Got error : ", e)
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

#### MY PROBLEM :

I populate the queue using `producer.py`.
Then I run  `consumer.py` script in multple terminal as separate processes.

What's happening is, things don't happen in parallel, like it happened in celery.

Although there are 3  processes to consume message, while a task is being processed inside one of the consumer process, nats server doesn't push any task to other 2 consumer.  Everything happens one after another.

I cannot figure out what I could be doing wrong. Could it be because my use-case is for CPU-bound task ? I also tried doing early acknowledgement of message `await msg.ack()` before running the `time_consuming_task()`.
To be honest, I am new to this domain of async programming.

Comment: Wonder if you had any luck implementing this yet because I am trying to move away from Celery+redis due t not handling async/await

Comment: @Amirsalar Using a pull consumer works fine. https://github.com/nats-io/nats-server/issues/4389#issuecomment-1674307680 . This is the solution I posted.